# Can you change your name in Animal Crossing City Folk?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

Can you change your name in Animal Crossing City Folk? I want to change my character's name but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately you cannot change your name once you've confirmed it. The only thing you can do for your official name is either restart your character. If you want, you can have the nickname that villagers call you be the name that you want to change to, but it'll only be a "nickname", not your official name.

Alternatively, if you're really far in the game and you don't want to take all the time and effort to unlock things again, you could make another character and move them into the same town, play that character, use the name you want that way.